# Cordova file copy from www folder to data/data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I put a file in my `data.txt`file `www` folder of ionic app. I just want to copy this file to another folder more specifically in `data/data` folder. Before copying I wrote a code to check if it exists or not?

```
function checkIfFileExists(path) {
        alert("file path : " + path);
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
        }, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
    }
    function fileExists(fileEntry) {
        alert("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
    }
    function fileDoesNotExist() {
        alert("file does not exist");
    }
    function getFSFail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }

    checkIfFileExists(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/index.html');
```

This code returns `file does not exist` why??.

That why I am unable to copy my db file. If this is not the way, anyone can help to use a pre-populated database in `cordova` app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to copy a database from www folder to native SQL database.

https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy

Sample usage:

```
window.plugins.sqlDB.copy(dbname, location, success,error);
```

Then use this plugin to access the database.

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/storage-master/README.md

Sample usage.

```
var db = null;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'demo.db', location: 'default'});
});
```

Comment: I am actually using `Corodova-sqlite-storage` plugin to work with sqlite. When I use browser it works fine. But I want my prepopulated database in mobile. That's why I put database in `www` folder and wanted to copy.

Comment: The fist plugin I listed will copy a pre-populated database from www to native sqlite. All you have to do is include the database file in the www folder and follow the documentation to move the database.